# Correr CMD en PHP

Tags: php, cmd

**Resumen**

Necesitaba  correr una linea de CMD por medio de PHP, busque documentación y no entendía, Y con los ejemplos no me servían, hasta que pude hallar una solución.

Espero les ayude mi pequeño aporte

Comment: Si realizas este tipo de aportes en las preguntas, que no se si son demasiado aconsejables porque para ti seguramente es un gran hallazgo, pero para otros quizás no tanto, mejor que en las respuestas pongas enlaces a la documentación de las funciones que estás usando donde puedan encontrar la información completa, sino es una respuesta de baja calidad pues es solo código sin más, como si de magia se tratara, cuando aquí se pretende ofrecer siempre un contexto donde ampliar la información de las respuestas para mayor comprensión de las mismas por parte de los que lleguen a verlas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solucion**

La solucion es simple, solo se tiene que ejecutar este codigo:

```
$cmd='ping google.com'; //insertamos la linea de CMD que queremos ejecutar 
$outx=shell_exec($cmd); 
echo "<pre>$outx</pre>";
```

Comment: Si ejecuto tu ejemplo en Linux no funciona como esperas. El comando `ping` nunca termina en Linux (en windows creo que lo hace al cabo de 4 pings), por lo tanto no devuelve nada, se queda ejecutándolo siempre. Aparte del `shell_exec()` tienes el `exec()`, el `system()`, el `passthru()`, el `pcntl_exec()`, el operador de comilla invertida, y seguramente alguno más. Normalmente en casi todos los hostings los dehabilitan para evitar accesos indeseados al shell por parte de malware si el sitio está infectado.